# How does one determine whether a polynomial has a double root?

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

Given the following function:
$$x^{3}+x^{2}+2x+8=0$$

The roots are $-3$, and $-1$.

However, $-3$ is counted as a double root, all three roots are $-3, -3, -1.$

My question is, how is it determined that $-3$, but not $-1$, is the double root?

Comment: I think you have the wrong function$$(x+3)^2(x+1)\neq x^3+x^2+2x+8$$

Comment: There is no double root for this equation. If $a$ is a double root then the deriavtive must vanish at $a$.

Comment: $-3$ is not a double root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeated roots of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733578/repeated-roots-of-a-polynomial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This equation does not have $-3$ or $-1$ as solutions, so I'll instead focus on one which does:

$$x^3 + 7 x^2 + 15 x + 9 = 0$$

Here, $-1$ is a "single" nonrepeated root, and $-3$ is a double root.

---

Why? It's quite simple: it's because you can write

$$x^3 + 7 x^2 + 15 x + 9 = (x-(-3))(x-(-3))(x-(-1))$$

In general, if a polynomial $f$ has roots $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ and leading coefficient $a$, you can write

$$f(x) = a (x-r_1)(x-r_2) \cdots (x-r_n)$$

and if the factor $(x-r)$ appears $m$ times, you say $r$ is a root of multiplicity $m$. ($m=2$ being double roots, $m=3$ being triple roots, and so on.)

Another way to look at it, it is because $(x+3)^2$ evenly divides $x^3 + 7 x^2 + 15 x + 9$, resulting in another polynomial, but $(x+3)^3$ will not.

Yet another way, it's because you can "factor out" or divide $x^3 + 7 x^2 + 15 x + 9$ by $x+3$, get a polynomial, and do it again. (In general if a root appeared $n$ times, then you could divide by the corresponding linear factor $n$ times but not $n+1$.)

---

An additional way is via calculus. If $r$ is a double root, you can write

$$f(x) = (x-r)^2 g(x)$$

Then by differentiation you see

$$f'(x) = 2(x-r) g(x) + (x-r)^2 g'(x)$$

Hence $f'(r) = 0$.